# Why does this class have parameters in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, class, oop, declaration

I searched so much to learn about this class declaration and what it means .. but I couldn't even find what this is called

```
Public MustInherent Class X ( Of TEntityBase, IBaseDataAccess As IBaseDataAccess ( Of TEntity)) 
     Implements IDisposable
.
.
.
```

**Why does this class have parameters?**
**What are they called? And what do they mean**

Note: I come from Java world.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a [generic class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w256ka79.aspx) which means that it is like a class template. Its like you have multiple class definitions that have the same structure and behavior, but deal with different types.

One example of such generic classes is the [`List(Of T)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) which you can use to create a list of strings, or a list of integers or a list of whatever element type that you want. There is a single `List(Of T)` class defined in the .NET framework, but because it is generic, you have `List(Of String)`, `List(Of Integer)` ..etc.

When you construct an object of type `X`, you need to specify the *generic type parameters* (e.g. `TEntityBase`).

In Java, you have a similar concept which is also called [Generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java).